# How to get RSSI (recevied signal power) in omnetpp (4.6) with inet 3.0?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm using [omnetpp4.6](/questions/tagged/omnetpp4.6) with [inet3.0](/questions/tagged/inet3.0).
I'm using IdealWirelessNic with IdealRadio,
where can i find the RSSI or SNR of the frame that rececvied in the physical layer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasted so much time to get obtained RxPower with Inet3.0 but i couldnt... I went back to inet2.6 and every thing is ok ... if u want to use inet 2.6 , I can help u to get rxPower...best luck...

Comment: Thanks, we succeed to reach Rx power after a very deep dig in inet 3.0 and add some changes in "IdealAnalogModel". Thanks anyway :)